# ¿Como puedo sumar los numero pares que estan adentro de mi vector?

Tags: python, array

Holaaaa, amig@s. He estado realizando la secuencia de collatz pero a la hora de realizar la suma de todos los numeros pares no se como hacerlos, ¿saben como hacerlo en python?

Ayudaaa por favor.

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que has intentado y describe más específicamente tu problema, lee [ask] y recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/486524/edit) tu pregunta las veces que sea necesario

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! luis, estas personas son como el mito de platón, su ignorancia esta en lo que tu dices, "se creen dueños de la verdad y el conocimiento" Tu eres grande y humilde, muchas gracias por ayudarme, ya lo probe y me salio a la perfección :D

Comment: La razon por la que a veces esperamos que alguien haya intentado algo es por que la persona tiene que aprender. Si le hacemos la tarea al op, este no aprende. Pero nadie dijo que no se pudiera ayudar. Puedes dejar un comentario guiando al op a la solucion.

Comment: De donde sacaste que queremos ayudar solo por puntos? A mi me gusta ganarlos, pero tambien ayudo por pasion a la programacion y el deseo de ayudar a otros. No obligo a nadie a que me apoye. Como mucho pido ese apoyo como un canal de youtuve pide suscriptores.

Comment: Cada uno tiene distintos niveles de conocimiento. Hay gente que tiene menos que vos y gente que tiene mas. Por ejemplo Abulafia me supera en conocimiento. No creo que nadie aqui se crea dueño de la verdad y el conocimiento @luisfelipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola tu problema es bastante sencillo. En las etiquetas vi que usas python, asi que lo resolvere con eso.

Si tu lista se llama `s`, la unica forma de tomar aquellos elementos que son pares es verificando uno a uno.

Para ello haremos una comparacion simple. Las comparaciones de paridad en Python se hacen asi: `a%2==0`. El operador `%` es en matematicas el resultado de congruencia, puedes entender `a%b` como el residuo de dividir `a` entre `b`. Al operar `a%2==0`, si este valor es `0`, pues resulta que `a` es par.

Ahora obtendremos  una sublista tomando unicamente los valores pares de `s`:

```
sublista = [x for x in s if x%2==0]
suma = sum(sublista)
```

---

---

**NOTA**

Dado a un error de lectura, pensé que se pedia sumar los elementos del vector de indice par, y como me quedó buena la explicación la mantendré aqui como una especie de "Anexos", ya que puede servir a otros y las reglas de la comunidad no indican que esto esté prohibido a la fecha de publicacion de esta respuesta.

si tu vector que contiene los numeros de Collatz es `s`, puedes hacer esto:

```
sum(s[1::2])
```

Te explico como funciona:

El vector tiene un indice de la siguiente forma en casi todos los lenguajes de programacion:

```
 s = [27, 82, 41, 124, 62, 31, 94, 47, 142]
      0    1   2   3   4   5   6    7   8
```

tu accedes a ellos con corchetes, por ejemplo `s[0]` es 27, `s[5]` es 32. Tambien puedes "barrer" el vector con la siguiente estructura.

```
s[indice de inicio : indice fin : tamaño de salto]
```

es decir, `s[3:7:1]` significa que empiezas en `s[3]`, hasta `s[7]` con saltos de 1 en 1.
Por ello, cuando hago `s[1::2]` estoy diciendo que empiece en `s[1]` porque es el primer numero par, el segundo parametro no lo pongo porque no quiero que tenga un final, quiero que recorra todo. Y el ultimo parametro le dice que vaya de 2 en 2, por ello tomara `s[1], s[3], s[5], ...` ya que como ves, son las posiciones de los elementos pares. Por ultimo aplico la funcion `sum()` que devuelve la suma de elementos de la sublista que generaste. Con esta explicacion ya puedes hacerlo en cualquier lenguaje ya que casi todos funcionan igual!

Comment: Ayuda a mantener la calidad del sitio y evita responder a preguntas de baja calidad. Además, sin conocer el código todo lo demostrado puede estar mal :(

Comment: El usuario pregunta por los números *pares*, pero no por los números en posiciones impares

Comment: Amigo, quiero sumar los numeros pares del vector, ademas de eso no conozco cuales son las posiciones de los numero pares ¿Como lo haria?

Comment: @Sam. Entiendo mejor tu pregunta, ahora mismo la edito para que entiendas. Respondeme si es cierto que necesitas la respuesta en python?

Comment: @Christian deja de acosarme.  La pregunta es de muy alta calidad desde mi punto de vista.

Comment: Si, la necesito en python

Comment: Perdón? no te estoy acosando, si crees que es el caso puedes reportar mi comentario para que los moderadores se encarguen. Solo estoy dejando los comentarios para ayudar a mejorar las publicaciones :D

Comment: tu comentario no ayuda a que el OP obtenga una solucion. Solo hace todo lo contrario

Comment: También opino que la pregunta de @Sam no esta bien construida en función a como funciona la comunidad, de todas formas creo que la respuesta  de Luis Felipe es útil y puede de ser utilidad no solo para Sam, sino para otros usuarios!

Comment: No todo se trata del OP, sino también de otros futuros lectores. Mi problema no es con tu repuesta, sino con la pregunta. Tu respuesta cumple con todos lo lineamientos del sitio y explica bien las cosas (por lo que he dado un voto a favor).  No entiendo por qué las personas se exaltan con cosas que no les afecta \\_(°-°)_/

Comment: Tu respuesta es excelente, y muy bien explicada c: se nota tu objetivo de hacer que el otro aprenda. Sin embargo, ten cuidado, algunas personas vienen a este sitio a publicar preguntas solo para que le hagan la tarea sin ningun esfuerzo de parte de ellos. Un ejemplo muy comun es aquellos que pegan el enunciado de un ejercicio en una pregunta y la publican. No queremos ayudar a gente que no quiere esforzarse por su cuenta.

Comment: Algunas personas como yo, en lugar de votar negativo, en preguntas como estas dejamos un comentario pidiendo al autor de la pregunta que agregue el codigo que logro hacer.

Comment: Yo prefiero hacerle la tarea bien explicada, que la lea y realmente comprenda. En la universidad tuve la oportunidad de ser docente de preuniversitarios, y muchos de ellos no intentan por miedo a fracasar. Yo siento que ellos aprenderan mas con una buena explicacion y resolucion, y perderan el miedo a intentarlo por si solos. Increpandolos a que se guien de las normas de la comunidad, o que no hagan copiar y pegar no les ayudara en nada sino a incrementar ese miedo a intentarlo. Una vez superado ese miedo, nadie los puede parar en el aprendizaje.

Comment: Si fueras profesor, le harias la tarea a tus alumnos por su miedo a fracasar? O los ayudarias orientandolos y dandoles pistas de como hacerlo? Te diria que plantees en meta estas cosas (aunque dijiste que no perderias el tiempo alli). Posiblemente la mayoria este en desacuerdo, pero vale la pena intentarlo y plantearlo. Yo logre convencer a los moderadores con el apoyo de la comunidad en agregar el link "por que me votaron negativo?" en como elaboro una buena pregunta.

Comment: Quiza en meta o en el chat encuentres a alguien que este de acuerdo contigo.

Comment: y qué gano con que alguien de ahi esté de acuerdo conmigo?  no se hagan problemas, si no les gusta la pregunta solo pasen a la siguiente, para que pierden el tiempo dejando comentarios que no ayuden a resolver el problema. Si fuera profesor haria mil ejemplos hasta que quede claro que a lo que tanto temen en realidad es sencillo, pero no lo soy!

Comment: Si no me hiciera problema, seria una persona menos a la que ayudaria. Dejar esos comentarios tambien es ayudar. Yo creo que cuando uno enseña, es como un profesor.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, de acuerdo a tus comentarios es muy importante revises cómo se deben realizar preguntas en el sitio [ask], ya que de otra forma contribuyes a que se publiquen preguntas que no son de calidad y que únicamente son de utilidad al OP pero no para la comunidad lo cual es el objetivo del sitio, saludos.